# How to implement these design guidelines components

Tags: android, google-maps, layout, android-cardview, android-coordinatorlayout

reading [this](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html) this article I see two images of two components/layouts that I would like to implement in my android application.

**BottomSheet**

[image]

**CoordinatorLayout with map and details**

[image]

How can I implement these layout structures? 
There is some easy way to implement these components or I have to create them myself? In that case could anyone post here some examples?

Thanks all in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

There is an open source library AndroidSlidingUpPanel provided by the Umano team. That seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

Here is the link

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

**Update:**

With the new Design Support Library 23.2, adding Bottom Sheets has become very easy. By attaching a `BottomSheetBehavior` to a child View of a `CoordinatorLayout` (i.e., adding `app:layout_behavior=”android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior”`), you can get the desired bottom sheet effect.